# Calculation of surface area of 3D model, then color filtering

Tags: python, mesh, color

I just got into blending and 3D modeling and I'm still not sure I understood how UV cards work.

I made a textured 3D model using the photogrammetry technique.
The idea now is to calculate the area of ​​my model where the color is green.
The first idea that came to me was to work on the model's UV map.

Step 1: Calculation of the total number of pixels of the UV map.

Step 2: Calculation of the total surface of the model.

Step 3: Calculate the number of green pixels in the UV map.

Step 4: Cross product to determine the green surface of the model.

However, by having gone through the various topics relating to similar problems, it seems to be more complicated.

One of the solutions seems to be to browse my 3D model and use the calc.area function
(or something like that -> [How to get the value of face area using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150797/how-to-get-the-value-of-face-area-using-python) ) on each face of each mesh, having also filtered out the colored (green) meshes upstream.

It is therefore necessary first of all to extract the RGB value of each face corresponding to the pixel (UV coordinates) of my texture image, in particular using a baricentric average calculation.

-> [Get RGB value of texture from face on mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139384/get-rgb-value-of-texture-from-face-on-mesh)

Do the proposed solutions seem viable to you? I accept any remark.

Comment: You sound extremely confused as to what a UV map is and does. A UV map has no pixel size. Each vertex in the UV map has a factor (IE 0 to 1) position on a two dimensional plane. Those two dimensions are U and V. The idea of a UV map is to tell Blender how a two dimensional image should be folded over a three dimensional object.

Comment: Yes, I am, but maybe less than you ...
There are definitely some colored pixels in the UV map. I never spoke of "pixel size". I'm just wondering if it's possible to relate the pixels of the UV map to the surface of the 3D model.

I understood that the UV map was used to correctly place the vertices on the 3D model.

Comment: No. UV Mavs are completely independent of images, and have no color association whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe I'm talking about the texture file that goes with it ...

Comment: That makes more sense. The first method you described would of course not work because most of the image could be squashed onto one tiny face in the model, while the rest of the image was stretched over the vast majority of the model. The second method sounds like it would work at least to some degree. How precise does this need to be? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I m trying to have an estimation of a surface vegetation parameter, in fact : the "green" surface of a bunch of vegetation, which represents the capacity of photosynthesis of the plant.